# Ubuntu 16.04 : No Ethernet cable and system not detecting WiFi paired with "Low graphics problem" . Tried everything online still nothing

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, graphics

after much search and unable to find a solution to this problem I am starting to think I have a unique/difficult case.

After rebooting the system following the initial install I faced the "Low Graphics Problem". I searched the Internet and found this extremely helpful link:

[How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I tried to do it the  Recovery Mode -> FailsafeX way but was unable to get in.

After this i went to the cli. There I realized that my computer is not connected to the internet.

After reading some questions online and some helpful troubleshooting  in #ubuntu in freenode.net. I tried to get more information by entering the following commands:

- lspci -nnk -d :0280   # this resulted in blank, nothing came up
- ubuntu-drivers list   # showed one isntalled driver for the Nvidia graphics card. Also tried to install the same graphics card on the suggestion of a freenode contributor but that effort failed.
- tried nmtuid but there are no wifi connections shown.
- sudo lsusb and sudo lspci # listed devices but did not have the wireless card in there.
- sudo lsmod  # this also did not have the wireless card listed.

Along with this I have tried all the ways to trouble shoot listed in many ask ubuntu question. I couldn't apply them primarily because the solutions required an internet connection.

also along the way I found this awesome article.

https://www.datamation.com/open-source/overcoming-ubuntu-wi-fi-not-working.html

I read it but I am not very technical at all. I tried to follow along but couldn't after the writer started manually loading the modules.

Also if it helps I have a Asus Z370-e motherboard. I have an Nvidia graphics card.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Just to check - you have recently had this system connected to WiFi? Does it work when booting from the installation media? Is your WiFi adapter built in, or do you have a USB dongle; can you test with a spare dongle? Is the router-modem in the same room?

Comment: I have a similar experience... When I switch on my laptop (HP Mini) with out pulling any strings... it boots but just before showing login greeter it gives me an "Low graphic error".. then I have to chose some options to fix this problem and pass... after login I see the Wifi device is not ready!... BUT IF at GRUB I chose "Recovery Mode" and in the action selection I chose to just "BOOT NORMALLY"... It boots without any single graphic error or problem connecting wifi... I want to get rid of this "going to grub and select RECOVERY mode, each time I want to turn on my Laptop!" PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem on several systems.
I noticed that:

- WiFi shows: device not ready.
- Wired connection does not work.
- The keybord is set to default (en), not "it" as set.
- Sometimes it boots correctly.

Re-install linux-header* linux-image* lightdm*  don't solve the problem.

#### Workaround:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, login, then:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

At least this works... I can login with graphic, wifi, keyboard etc. All work correctly... for one time!